# Controlling ListBoxItem  height inside wrap panel 

Tags: wpf, height, listboxitem

I have defined a `WrapPanel` as `ListBoxItems` template:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I have 3 `ListboxItem`s per row.

My `ListBoxItem` expands when selected. When I select a `ListBoxItem`, it expands but other two `ListBoxItem`s in same row also expand to the same height of selected one.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Thank you, 
Mar

**Edit:**
Image Added
http://www.flickr.com/photos/themarworld/3953597593/

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1197/listboxonselctissue.jpg](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1197/listboxonselctissue.jpg)

Comment: It's funny because I'm working on a similar UI.  When I saw this behavior, I said "wow that is actually good".  In your example say you selected the first item in your second row, and only that item expanded.  Then item 5 and 6 would wrap under each other which I would think would be bad also.

In your example it would be cool if the row became the max height of any single item, but only one item expanded.  That would avoid the other items wrapping, but only show one expanded item.

Did you set an explicit height on your non expanded items - that might do the trick?

Comment: @Jon- I expected SO will mail me when someone adds comments:-(.  You are talking exactly the same functionality that I am thinking of ( Row becomes maximum height of item but only selected item is expanded) I haven't set the height explicitly because I was thinking if content height ( large text with wrap)  is variable due to its content Explicit height may not be possible. I will play with explicit height and update this section with results.